# How do I compile a library into a lib/ folder?

Tags: c++, cmake, cmake-format

This is my first time using CMake as a developer, and I want to compile some libraries for my project into a lib/ folder.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and running CMake from the command line.

There's 2 libraries I wish to use:

- Magick++
- https://github.com/ljfa-ag/libnbtplusplus

(I'm also using TCLAP but that's implemented entirely in headers.)

I know about and am using the standard folder layout (`bin/`, `build/`, `include/`, `src/`, etc).

The libraries (especially libnbt++) are specific for this project and I don't want to install them globally. How do I compile them into my `lib/` folder?

Comment: Just pass proper `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<...>` option to `cmake`.

Comment: @tsyvarev What do you mean by "proper"?

Comment: Value of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` means **installation prefix** of the project. So libraries are usually installed under `lib/` subdirectory of that prefix, headers - under `include/` subdirectory and so on.

Comment: So set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/Projects/CppThing/lib/Magick++` or something? (PS remember to post as actual answer, you deserve rep)

Comment: Yes, you may specify a user's home directory or its subdirectory as an installation prefix. (I am not sure, but it is better to avoid `~` in the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable, because it may be expanded incorrectly sometimes. You may use `$HOME` instead, which is expanded immediately). Not sure that I want a reputation for a question which is so easily googled...